# Calling PHP file from a slider page, how do I return to the active slide?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a simple home-grown slider whose input is pulled from a MySQL database using PHP that echos the HTML for the slider page to build it.  I am developing functionality to "add a comment" to the slider pictures which pulls up a hidden form when you click on the "Add a Comment" button.  Once filling in that form and doing a Submit, I call an "updateComment.php" file that pulls the form posted values and does a CONCAT_WS to the Comments field for that picture in the slider sequence in the database.

I use a header('Location: ' .$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); call at the end of the "updateComment.php" file to return to the slider page whose form submit called it.   When it returns, it returns to the first slide page instead of the active slide page.  **It makes sense to me why that happens using that redirect method, but I am at a loss to figure out how to get it to return to the active slide page.**  I've been reading up on PHP redirects, but can't find anything that will work.  **Any sage words of advice or a clue how to do this?**

Doing a Page Source of the slider page and stripping out all the detailed database field info built on that page, here is the code around the form's call to "updateComment.php".

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
   <button class="commentbutton" onclick="showForm('formElementTimothyTopp')">Add a memory or story of Tim</button> 
</div>
<div>
  <form id="formElementTimothyTopp" style="display: none;" action="updateComment.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
     <input type="hidden" value="Timothy" id="fname" name="fname">
     <input type="hidden" value="Topp" id="lname" name="lname">
     <div class="formitemname">Name:</div>
     <input class="formitem shortentry" type="text" maxlength="40" value="" id="commentor" name="commentor" placeholder="Your Name">
     <div class="formitemnamelonger">Your Memory or Story of Tim:</div>
     <textarea class="formitem longentry" type="text" maxlength="2000" value="" id="memory-story" name="memory-story" placeholder="Add your memory or story here" rows="5"></textarea>
     <button style="text-align: center; margin: 10px 0 10px 240px;" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
<div>
```

Here is the actual "updateComments.php" code

```
<?php
   $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "classmateinfo");
   if ($conn-> connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed:". $conn-> connect_error);
   }
   $firstname = $_POST['fname'];
   $lastname = $_POST['lname'];
   $memory = !empty($_POST['memory-story'])?$_POST['memory-story']:'';
   $name = !empty($_POST['commentor'])?$_POST['commentor']:'';
   $toappend = $memory . "<br>-- " . $name . "<br><div><img src=images/spacer10.gif></div>";
   $sql = "UPDATE rip SET Comments = CONCAT_WS('',Comments,'$toappend') WHERE (ClassmateNameFirst = '$firstname' AND ClassmateNameLast = '$lastname')";
   $result = $conn-> query($sql);
   header('Location: ' .$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
?>
```

Slider functional code is:

```
<script>
function showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides"); 
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1};
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length};
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
     slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

The rest of the info on the slider page besides the active image displayed includes the Comments field and that page is built using an HTML table.  Each slider page is its own table, dozens of images with a table entry for each, all built by the database pulls using PHP code to render the page.

Comment: Now that I typed this all up, maybe I could do something with bookmarking each slide when building the page.  Could I then redirect to the bookmark in the calling URL?  What would that redirect statement look like?

Comment: The bookmark idea did not pan out.  Still brings you back to the first slide.  I'll see if I can pull the updateComments.php functionality into the slider page code next, but I don't want to do that because it will be used by other slider pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea is to submit `current_slide` along with the form. Then server knows to redirect back to page with extra param `"$page?current_slide=" . $current_slide;`. This param would then be analyzed when initializing the slider, to start from the correct slide.

Some code:

```js
function update_current() {
  var current_slide = 12; // get from slider
  document.getElementById("current_slide").value = current_slide;
}
```

```html
<form id="formElementTimothyTopp" style="display: none;" onsubmit="update_current()" action="updateComment.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="hidden" value="Timothy" id="fname" name="fname">
  <input type="hidden" value="Topp" id="lname" name="lname">
  <input type="hidden" value="" id="current_slide" name="current_slide">
  <div class="formitemname">Name:</div>
  <input class="formitem shortentry" type="text" maxlength="40" value="" id="commentor" name="commentor" placeholder="Your Name">
  <div class="formitemnamelonger">Your Memory or Story of Tim:</div>
  <textarea class="formitem longentry" type="text" maxlength="2000" value="" id="memory-story" name="memory-story" placeholder="Add your memory or story here" rows="5"></textarea>
  <button style="text-align: center; margin: 10px 0 10px 240px;" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then on server:

```php
// TODO: append query string parameter in a better way
header('Location: ' .$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "?current_slide=" . $_POST["current_slide"]);
```

Then back on load of client:

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const current_slide = urlParams.get('current_slide');

// TODO: goto slide current_slide
```

UPDATE:

another idea would be using the `localStorage` to store the state of the slider right before submitting it. Then, when loading all you need is `getItem` from `localStorage` and check it.

```js
// when submitting
function update_current() {
  var current_slide = 12; // get from slider
  localStorage.setItem("current_slide", current_slide);
}


// when loading the page call:
function load_current() {
  var current_slide = localStorage.getItem("current_slide")
  if (current_slide) {
    // set slider slide to be current_slide
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your ideas ... I will see if I can figure out how to add this in and give it a test.  Will then post my results and see if I can tag your suggestion as the answer.  Really appreciate your response!

Comment: There's another option. Maybe even better. I'll update my answer

Comment: I'm looking at this, but the problem is that the slider page always starts with the first slide.  The only way to tell it to go to a specific slide is by calling an internal function within that slider page which does a slide swap to the slide desired after the page is already built.  I'm an old school coder, who expects a called routine to return back to where it's called from.  I'm a fledgling web developer who only does this sporadically.  I'll  keep at this until I figure out a way to do this.

Comment: I don't understand what to do with the urlParams portion of your suggested code.  I'll read up on that.  Frustrated ...

Comment: if you are on `https://some.page/?current_slide=12` then you want to get that value 12 using urlParams

Comment: I think I understand the implementation part now, I just need to rewrite a chunk of the slider code to accommodate changing the active slide on load.  The way it's written on load it defaults to the first slider.  I tried to mark your suggestion as the answer, but I guess I don't have enough reputation points to do that.  Thanks again for your time and help!

Comment: It's alright it is now marked as answered. I had one last idea but might be complicated is on the server side to echo the images for the slider page according to what should be first. this goes back to solution number 1.

Comment: Not sure who marked my post unhelpful, but I did do a lot of research on redirects and many hours on thinking this through before I created the post.  I was trying to find a redirect that didn't require a major rewrite of my code.  I am a newbie to this level of web development, in my-mid 60s, and appreciate all the help I can get ... regardless of what the StackOverflow admins think.